# How to apply IVT to prove there exist a c in (a,b)?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and suppose that $f(a) \ne f(b).$ Prove that there is a number $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $$f(c) = \frac{1}{5}f(a)+ \frac{4}{5}f(b)$$.

How to apply IVT to this?

Answer (score 2):

wlog assume $f(a) < f(b)$ then $f(a)<\frac{1}{5}f(a)+ \frac{4}{5}f(b)<f(b)$. Now apply IVT.

Comment: I think strictly speaking you cannot say "WLOG" but you have to break into two cases since the expression is not symmetric.

Comment: @cr001 I do not kow if you feel wiki is reliable or not but according to the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) it says " it implies that the proof for that case can be easily applied to all others, or that all other cases are equivalent or similar".

Comment: I don't think the processes $\frac{1}{5}f(a)+ \frac{4}{5}f(b)<\frac{1}{5}f(b)+ \frac{4}{5}f(b)$ when $f(a)<f(b)$ and $\frac{1}{5}f(a)+ \frac{4}{5}f(b)<\frac{1}{5}f(a)+ \frac{4}{5}f(a)$ when $f(b)<f(a)$ are easily applied to each other though. Yes they themselves are both trivial but I don't think one can be applied to the other as the coefficients are different. Imagine if one had a negative coefficient then we couldn't even apply anything.

Comment: @cr001 I am sorry but I do not understand why the method is not similar also I did not understand what you were saying about the negative coefficients

Comment: Happymath "wlog" is totally fine imo. If $f(a)>f(b)$, consider $-f$...

Comment: @sranthrop I too believe that wlog is fine but I have gotten downvote on this answer which to me looks perfectly fine

Comment: What I meant was if you have something like $-\frac{1}{5}f(a)+ \frac{6}{5}f(b)<-\frac{1}{5}f(b)+ \frac{6}{5}f(b)$ when $f(a)>f(b)$ you cannot apply anything similar to the case $f(a)<f(b)$. I did not downvote your answer but if you got a downvote I would think the person who downvoted may think the same way as I do.

Comment: @cr001 thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(b)>f(a)$ .Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-\dfrac{f(a)}{5}-\dfrac{4}{5}f(b)$.

Then $g(a)<0;g(b)>0$ Since $f$ is continuous so is $g$ By IVP $\exists $c\in(a,b)$ $ such that $g(c)=0$

Answer (score 0):

If p< q and $0<x<1$ then p x+ q(1-x) lies between  p and q . Because $p=p x+p(1-x)<p x+q(1-x)<q x+q(1-x)=q.$ Apply this with p=min (f(a),f(b)) and q=max (f(a),f(b)) and x=1/5.